# Macbook Air 6'2 installation issues (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, macbook-air

I'm trying to install 14.04 through a USB stick. I plugged the usb stick in and got all the way through the installation process but after I rebooted and tried to load in through Grub I got just a blank screen. So then I put noapic at the end of the line that starts with vmlinuz after pressing e at the grub menu.

(I followed this guide: http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-in-macbook-air)

But now when I try to load ubuntu from the grub menu all I get is a black screen with a cursor. What do i do?

edit: I reinstalled 14.04 and this time i installed refind with it. For some reason it had an option when I clicked to load into Ubuntu from refind screen that it loaded in automatically if I didn't do anything for 10 seconds. It actually loaded in and I was able to install drivers and get updates on everything. But now that I shut my laptop off for the night I'm back at the beginning.. I can't get back into Ubuntu..

edit 2: after running partition inspector I got this:

*** Report for internal hard disk ***

Current GPT partition table:
 #      Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1             40       409639  EFI System (FAT)
 2         409640    170309775  Mac OS X HFS+
 3      170573824    229165055  Basic Data
 4      229165056    236976127  Basic Data

Current MBR partition table:
 # A    Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1              1       409639  ee  EFI Protective
 2         409640    170309775  af  Mac OS X HFS+
 3 *    170573824    229165055  83  Linux
 4      229165056    236976127  82  Linux swap / Solaris

MBR contents:
 Boot Code: Unknown, but bootable

Partition at LBA 40:
 Boot Code: None (Non-system disk message)
 File System: FAT32
 Listed in GPT as partition 1, type EFI System (FAT)

Partition at LBA 409640:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: HFS Extended (HFS+)
 Listed in GPT as partition 2, type Mac OS X HFS+
 Listed in MBR as partition 2, type af  Mac OS X HFS+

Partition at LBA 170573824:
 Boot Code: GRUB
 File System: ext4
 Listed in GPT as partition 3, type Basic Data
 Listed in MBR as partition 3, type 83  Linux, active

Partition at LBA 229165056:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: Unknown
 Listed in GPT as partition 4, type Basic Data
 Listed in MBR as partition 4, type 82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: That guide didn't work for me either. I had success with this one though.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Trusty

Comment: This one too, if you want to go grub free. Just create/adjust the refind_linux.conf file in your /boot directory. (Refind website has a great writeup on it). Make the options line match the grub options line from the first guide. Ie. Add in the i915 parameters. https://github.com/aroman/freya-on-a-mac

Comment: Im browsing from my phone right now, so If this doesn't make sense let me know and I'll explain with a proper detailed answer as soon as I can.

Comment: I guess I'll uninstall Ubuntu and give it another go following amanthethy's guide.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the instructions like it says well, then you installed rFEIt. This is a nice program, but it does have an error, that it doesn't read the partition tables right or something. To fix this, (Hopefully getting it to work!) you have to go to the partition inspector and say yes to syncing the partition tables. After that, is should work.
I've been working on this for the last 2 weeks, and I still haven't been able to get ubuntu, but still working on it... :)

Comment: Try the first guide I posted. I have a 6,2 and it worked with no problems on the first try.

Comment: I ran partition inspector how do I paste what I found in here without it being too long to comment?

Comment: @halphalphalp As far as I'm concerned, that would solve the problem and you wouldn't need to add what you found in partition inspector.